# How to get specific parameter value from a given value php

Tags: php

if $url = 'http://yalumalu.com/watch_video.php?v=UXNWH2YA43RU'; is my url,

how to get value in the parameter "V=" ?

I tried using explode url but it returns an empty value? hlp me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to consider @Brad suggestion

```
$pos = strpos($url,'?') + 1;

parse_str(substr($url,$pos),$arg);
echo $arg['v'];
```

Comment: What happens when there are other parameters after the `v`?  This fails.

Comment: This is not fixed!  `parse_str()` does not return values.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: It's **still** not correct.  You'd need to use $v, not $arg['v'], and this is a scary solution anyway, as stray variables in the URL could overwrite needed stuff in code.

Comment: @Brad: you are terribly wrong about using `$v`. So please now toggle that -1. As this answers perfectly the question. Thank you :)

Comment: No, by adding `$arg` to `parse_str()`, it gets added to `$arg`.  So it  could not overwrite variables.  From the manual: __If the second parameter arr is present, variables are stored in this variable as array elements instead.__

Comment: there was a error with ur code but incombination f everyones replies n using php manual i build my own code! thanks guys!

Comment: $url = 'http://yalumalu.com/watch_video.php?v=UXNWH2YA43RU&up=1';




$query = parse_url($url);


$str = $query['query'];
parse_str($str);

echo $v;

Comment: @NaveenChamikaraGamage: ok :) if my answer helped you consider to +1 it! thanks

Comment: im sry friend it says Vote Up requires 15 reputation btw i marked ur answer as a correct one.hope it helps u n once again thankssss..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parse_url:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

Should give

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

So you'd want something like:

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

var_dump($parsedUrl['query']);

$result = explode('=', $parsedUrl['query']);

$v = $result[1];

var_dump($v);
```

Which should output

```
UXNWH2YA43RU
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The path is not needed, a specific parameter within query is.

Comment: I really need is value in da 'V' parameter! how to get V from array?

Comment: @NaveenChamikaraGamage: look at my answer naveen :)

Comment: it returns da result arg=value which extractly means to 'v=UXNWH2YA43RU'
but i just need da value! UXNWH2YA43RU